# Гол!... - нет - штанга!

Tags: лексикон, заимствования

Русская футбольная терминология естественно заимствована из английского. Многое было переведено на русский, многое русским освоено, кое-что продолжает существовать в обоих вариантах.

Есть, однако, загадочное слово "штанга". Вероятно, флотско-голландского происхождения (ср. [стеньга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0)). Для порядка уточняю, что англичане называют эту часть ворот post, а эту часть мачты - topmast.

Собственно, вопрос: как эта штанга попала в футбольный лексикон?

PS Уточнение на ответ **VV**:

Если почитать источники 20х (Старостин) и 30х (Кассиль) годов, то станет ясно, что *штанга* - устоявшися термин, наряду с пропавшими с те пор *беком* и *хафбеком* (к слову, *форвард* и *голкипер* все еще употребляются). Слово же *бомбардир* (в русском языке со времен Петра) к футболу получает отношение не раньше 50х годов.

Answer (score 8):

На самом деле, хотя в стандартном немецком эта часть футбольных ворот называется (во множественном числе) Torfposten, в австрийском немецком они часто так и называются - штанги (Stangen).

Вот [цитата](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(Fu%C3%9Fball)) из немецкой википедии:

> In Österreich werden Torpfosten oft als Stangen bezeichnet

(В Австрии стойки часто называются штангами)

Варианта два - в русском эту часть ворот стали называть штангами независимо от немцев (ну то есть ясно, что слово немецкое, но часть футбольных ворот так стали называть независимо в обоих языках) - или же в русский оно пришло через те диалекты немецкого, где это тоже называлось штангой. Второй вариант по понятным причинам мне кажется более вероятным.

Что же касается того, когда это называли штангой в немецком - я задал вопрос [на немецком стеке](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36035/was-stangen-initially-used-more-often-for-football-gates).

UPD: на немецком стеке говорят, что "штанга" раньше действительно говорили чаще.

Comment: Замечательная находка.  Она особенно любопытна тем что в немецком Брокгаузе используется 'Stangen', a в русском Брокгаузе-Ефроне это переведено как 'жердь' (т.е. использован русский эквивалент.)

Comment: Интересно. Но все равно непонятно.

Comment: @Vitaly в ЭСБЕ написано следующее -  "посредине черты ставятся ворота из жердей" - я так понимаю, что речь идёт о том, что сетки не было, а вместо них - жерди.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, изначально сетки не было.  Первый раз сетка была использована в [1891-м](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0).
 Более того, в воротах из жердей
 могло не быть верхней жерди.

Answer (score 2):

While most of Russian football terminology has been borrowed or calqued from English indeed, there are lots of terms which are either original Russian or borrowed or calqued from other languages: *ворота* (and *вратарь*), *одиннадцатиметровый, бровка, девятка, вне игры* etc.

*Штанга* is just one of them. It apparently has been borrowed from construction jargon, where it means a round hollow pole used in light-weight frame structures (such as a football goal).

Comment: Most of the terms you've mentioned were invented much later. In twenties _форвард_ бил по _голу_, где стоял _голкипер_. At least till seventies street football said _пеналь_ (remember три корнера - пеналь?) and _в овсе_ (that's for _offside_, just in case). Offhand I can only recall _крайний_ (for _wing_ is very foreign to Russian phonetics). Construction jargon version is very promising.

Answer (score -2):

В 90% случаев слово, которое начинается на "Ш" и имеет второй буквой согласную заимствовано из немецкого, в котором правила предполагают чтение первой S  в таком случае как Ш. Идем в google-translate, переключаем German->russian, вбиваем Stange и...

> Translations of Stange
> noun
>
> штанга - Stange, Hantel, Latte
>
> рейка - Leiste, Latte, Stange
>
> столб - Säule, Stange, Pfosten, Pfahl, Pfeiler, Mast

Comment: это не ответ на вопрос, что штанга заимствована из немецкого в общем-то, насколько я понимаю, не подвергается сомнению в том числе и автором, но в немецком эта часть ворот штангой не называется. Отсюда в общем-то и вопрос - когда именно в русском эту часть ворот стали называть штангой и почему.

Comment: _Не подвергается сомнению в том числе и автором_ - как раз таки подвергается: _Русская футбольная терминология естественно заимствована из английского._